# Selecting Graphic Symbol On Click Android

Tags: arcgis-android, graphics

I'm using the arcGIS Android API with Android Studio, and I would like to know how to select a graphic symbol when a user taps on it. I have a graphics layer and I've added a couple picture marker symbols to it. I simply want to show a symbol as being selected when a user taps on it.

Creating the graphics:

```
graphicAirport_IAD = new Graphic(projIAD, pmsAirport);
graphicAirport_DCA = new Graphic(projDCA, pmsAirport);
graphicAirport_BWI = new Graphic(projBWI, pmsAirport);
```

Adding the graphics to map view:

```
mMapView.addLayer(gAirport);
gAirport.addGraphic(graphicAirport_IAD);
gAirport.addGraphic(graphicAirport_DCA);
gAirport.addGraphic(graphicAirport_BWI);
```

The graphics all show up fine. Again, I would just like to be able to select them when they're tapped on (respectively) by a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

1). Create a class that extends `MapOnTouchListener`:

```
 private class MyTouchListener extends MapOnTouchListener
```

2). In that class override the `onSingleTap` method:

```
public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent event)
```

3). You can get the coordinates for the the tap event with he following:

```
Point mapPoint = mMapView.toMapPoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

4). Select the graphic if it's coordinates match with the event point coordinates (with some tolerance).